# How to send an email directly from code (without server)

Tags: c#, email, smtp, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

Everytime I google or search here "how to send an email" I get results [like: use an smtp client, connect to a smtp server, send the mail over the smtp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809630/failure-sending-email-message).

I am looking for the code (or the idea) how the server it self sends the email to the other server. So the approach from the link above won't work for me.

Any hints what a smtp server library would do?

Comment: So you want to build your own mail server? What do you find if you google for that?

Comment: @oerkelens No, I don't want to build my own mail server. I just want to write the code which sends an email (from an Web API). I do not care about receiving mails, storing mails, managing mails,....

Comment: To send an email you need a server. Period. You can use a cloud service like SendGrid if you don't have or want one yourself. If you are just looking for the idea behind a server than that is off topic for SO. *Any hints what a smtp server library would do?* Sure, an smtp server library connects to a mail server.

Comment: Why not look at source code of simple yet complete functional mailing solutions for .net core, like MailKit.

Comment: @MilanVidakovic MailKit does not support sending without an SMTP relay and discovering the destination server via DNS MX lookup. That's why other solutions needed, like suggested by Evk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **reliable** send an email you need a server. Period. You can use a cloud service like SendGrid if you don't have or want one yourself.

An smtp server is needed because otherwise:

- You will need to implement retries yourself of the other server is
  down
- Most mail servers have spam detection mechanisms in place and won't allow your mail
- You will have to resolve the recipient mail servers manually.

Some background reading material about the reasons I listened:
https://superuser.com/questions/1006079/why-do-i-need-an-smtp-server

https://superuser.com/questions/753811/why-mail-clients-do-not-use-directly-the-smtp-server-of-recipient

https://superuser.com/questions/753811/why-mail-clients-do-not-use-directly-the-smtp-server-of-recipient

Answer (score 10):

First you need to find out address of SMTP server for each of the recipients of your email. You do that by querying DNS of recipients domain for MX record(s). In .NET you can do that with, for example, `ARSoft.Tools.Net` library:

```
var resolver = new DnsStubResolver();
var records = resolver.Resolve<MxRecord>("gmail.com", RecordType.Mx);
foreach (var record in records.OrderByDescending(c => c.Preference)) {
    Console.WriteLine(record.ExchangeDomainName + " : " + record.Preference);
}
```

Each MX record has preference value, and you should try them in order of preference (highest first, then if it's not available - next one etc).

Now when you have address of target SMTP server - you connect to it (usually on port 25, or if you want to use encrypted connection - on port 465) and perform regular SMTP conversation (smtp is text protocol), for example:

```
HELO < you start conversation
250 OK < server lets you proceed
MAIL FROM: <someuser@somedomain.com>
250 OK < server is fine with this sender
RCPT TO: <someuser@targetdomain.com>
250 OK < server is fine with recipient
DATA < you are going to send email body
250 OK < server is fine with that - proceed
Here you send your message 
250 OK < server accepted message
QUIT
```

There are libraries which are capable of doing all this (MX discovery, SMTP conversations and more) in .NET, for example MailBee (not free). I used only mentioned library for this, so not aware if there are free libraries.

Now, while it might look easy - in reality it will not go as smooth as I described.

Target SMTP server will perform a series of checks agains your IP address, domain of the sender, and message contents. For example, when you do:

```
MAIL FROM: <someuser@somedomain.com>
```

Most decent SMTP servers will perform reverse DNS check to ensure that domain of a sender and IP from which you send your email are related. To pass that check you should of course own target domain (`somedomain.com`) and put specific DNS record there.

Most SMTP servers will "graylist" you on the first send. That means they will reject your email but encourage you to try later. So you cannot send emails without storing them, because it many cases - several tries are required to sucessfully send your email.

There are many more checks performed by SMTP servers (different kind of signatures for example), so some efforts are required to make this work reliably.

For the above reasons - most people do not implement their own smtp servers but instead relay all of the above work to already existing SMTP server.

To sum up - it's possible to perform direct send to target SMTP server, but doing that naively from your web api is not going to work reliably. You need to setup a service for that purpose, configure it correctly (not trivial) and store messages somewhere (in database), because several retries might be required.